# Navigating Between Pages in React Native using onPress method on a Button

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

In react Native I am using createStackNavigator to navigate between pages. In one of my components Home.js I wish to call a function postDataHandler() that will include navigating to the next page using navigate. When I call the navigate method inside another function (postDataHandler) it no longer will route to the next page. Why does this method only work outside my postDataHandler and how can I get it to work inside of this function?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

// Components
import Home from './Screens/Home';
import Profile from './Screens/Profile';
import AddAProfile from './Screens/AddAProfile';
import AddProfiles from './Screens/AddProfiles';
import ProfileInfo from './Screens/ProfileInfo';
import Profiles from './Screens/Profiles';
import RoutineDashboard from './Screens/RoutineDashboard';
import Landing from './Screens/Landing';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
    Landing: {screen: Landing},
    Home: { screen: Home },
    //Profile: { screen: Profile },
    AddAProfile: {screen: AddAProfile},
    AddProfiles: {screen: AddProfiles},
    ProfileInfo: {screen: ProfileInfo},
    Profiles: {screen: Profiles},
    RoutineDashboard: {screen: RoutineDashboard}
});

const App = createAppContainer(Navigator);

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
postDataHandler = () => {

        
         navigate(
            'AddProfiles', { name: 'AddProfiles' }
        )}

render() {

        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupbutton}>
                    <Button
                        color='white'
                        title="Sign Up"
                        onPress={() => this.postDataHandler()}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Comment: Do you get any error ? based on your code navigate is defined outside postDataHandler

Comment: I think, you forgot to pass `navigate` to `postDataHandler()` method.. it should be 

`postDataHandler = (navigate) => {
         navigate(
            'AddProfiles', { name: 'AddProfiles' }
        )}
render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupbutton}>
                    <Button
                        color='white'
                        title="Sign Up"
                        onPress={() => this.postDataHandler(navigate)}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
)}`

Comment: Yes the error I get is "Cant Find Variable Navigate"

Comment: You can simply call  this.props.navigation.navigate inside your function

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan this worked! Thank you for the help!